# When doing biterm topic modeling, how can I get the top documents for a topic returned in the original format?

Tags: python, nlp, topic-modeling

I literally don't know anything about coding, but I am in a situation, and I need help. I am topic modeling on a bunch of short text (comments) and I would like for the topic model to return the top documents and currently I have an output like this at the part where it says "Interactive report interface":

https://tmplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#Visualization

I understand what I am looking at, and I see that I have some version of the top documents for each topic, but  the "top documents" don't have stop words or anything, so they just seem like gibberish, and I want to read the original comments and export these original comments into a data file.

I am going insane for this simple thing and I don't know how to even start. I have tried everything and nothing. Please someone just give me the very simple answer, some code I can copy and paste. I don't need to understand how it works. I just want to be able to read the original documents. ANd if you can't give me the code please tell me how to learn and where I can read how to get the original top documents.